# How to Get DefaultSite from UserPreferences For Current User in Acumatica

Tags: c#, acumatica

This is for Acumatica ERP 2021 R2:

I need to get the Default Warehouse Site for the current user. This is shown as part of the UserPreferences DAC, and the field name is DefaultSite

[image: User Profile]

Getting the UserPreferences seems easy enough:

```
            var curUsr = base.Base.Accessinfo.UserID;
            var usrPrefs = UserPreferences.PK.Find(graph, curUsr);
```

The problem is that the DefaultSite does not exist in the UserReferences DAC!

It exists in the SQL database table:

[image: SQL SS]

How do I get the DefaultSite field? It is NOT available to me in the DAC. I need it to retrieve the INSite record it references.

Here is a screenshot of my VStudio showing available fields, you can see that DefaultSite is missing.

[image: VS Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DefaultSiteID is defined in the UserPreferenceExt DAC cache extension, so you just simply need to get the extension and use it like below:

```
var curUsr = base.Base.Accessinfo.UserID;
var usrPrefs = UserPreferences.PK.Find(graph, curUsr);

var usrPrefsExt = usrPrefs.GetExtension<UserPreferenceExt>();
var siteID = usrPrefsExt?.DefaultSite;
```

Comment: I should have thought to check that. Usually the extensions I have seen have the usr prefix, so I never considered this could be an extension, for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkJoel60 I agree, this is actually a little strange that they have that field in that extension.